# How do I pass a vector of unique_ptr s to a function

Tags: c++

How do I pass a vector of `unique_ptr` to a function to access each individual objects functions and variables? The pointers point to the derived class through base class `object`. The derived classes are for example, `triangle`, `plane`, `sphere` etc.

So far, I've been try to do this:

```
void foo(vector<unique_ptr<object>>& shapes)
{
    // do something
}
```

But the problem with this is that `unique_ptr` can't be copied. I don't know if creating a reference would work, but I assume I have to use the `move` function. That or I'm not sure if `shared_ptr` is a good idea. The objects are dynamically allocated.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Does the code you posted not compile?

Comment: The code you have posted is fine ; if you are still having trouble then please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: JerSci Is `foo()` a function that you can change or is it a function in an API to some library you are using? In case of the latter, please share the real signature of the function.

Answer (score 3):

> How to pass a vector of unique_ptr to a function to access each individual objects fucntions and variables

Do it as you have shown in the question. It works just fine.

> the problem with this is that unique_ptr can't be copied

That is not a problem, because the `unique_ptr`s are not being copied.

> I'm not sure if shared_ptr are a good idea.

No, they are not good idea unless you really need shared ownership.

Comment: The problem is that the ppm I'm trying to generate keeps failing. I'm passing it to foo from main as foo(objects) where object is already a vector of unique_ptrs. I think the reason the ppm fails to generate is because I have a line in my code that transfers ownership of a unique_ptr to another. It's like this:

Comment: closest = move(shapes[ j ])  where j is the integer number, shapes is the reference variable and closest a unique_ptr of the object type. I don't think I can use a reference variable for it, but i can't be sure

Comment: I just debugged it and that line is the cause for it failing. Help please?

Comment: @JerSci I don't know what "ppm" is. I suggest you ask a new question and post as much code as you can in a reproducible example. This way people will be able to see what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You either `std::move` the pointers into the vector or just put raw pointers in the vector using `ptr.get()`. In the latter case, be sure that the original pointers outlive the function you called. You can use `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr`if you are unsure about that.

Example with raw pointers:

```
void caller() {
    std::vector<object*> objs{uniqueptr1.get(), uniqueptr2.get()};
    foo(objs);
}

void foo(vector<object*>& shapes)
{
    ......//do something 
}
```